# Unable to get batch file variables to work

Tags: batch-file

```
echo off
echo %1%
echo %2

set web = %web%
curl -I %web%
```

I have tried and have not been able to get it to work.
My example file name is `aa.bat`

```
aa.bat https://www.google.com
```

This should result on the output of the command `curl -I https://www.google.com`

I cannot get it to return the required result.

Comment: the first parameter is referenced as `%1`, the second one as `%2` etc. Where do you take `%web%` from? And `set web = %web%` creates another variable `%web %` with the value of `%web%` (which is empty as far as we can see) preceded with a space.

Answer (score 1):

It is really not necessary to create a variable from `stdin`, but if it was needed:

```
@echo off
echo %1
echo %2   Rem Your example input does not show a second input parameter, so this will probably be nothing:
set "web=%~1"
curl -I "%web%"
pause
```

You can however just use the input `%1` as is:

```
@echo off
echo %1
echo %2
curl -I "%~1"
pause
```

Usage:

```
aa.bat http://www.google.com
```

result:

[image]

So here are some valuable hints. open `cmd` and type `help` where you will find a list of commands. For each of these commands you find interesting, type command name, followed by `/?` for instance. `set /?` You will be able to find alot of useful information that will help you better understand `batch-files` and `cmd`. Also remember to run the help for `cmd /?` itself.